# Does it follow from Gautschi's Inequality that $x^s > \frac{\Gamma(x+s)}{\Gamma(x)} > x(x+1)^{s-1}$

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, gamma-function

Here's my thinking.  Please let me know if any of my assumptions are incorrect.

(1)  From [Gautschi's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gautschi%27s_inequality), if $x > 0$ is real and $0 < s < 1$:

$$x^{1-s} < \frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(x+s)} < (x+1)^{1-s}$$

For this example, let's assume that $x$ is a positive integer.

(2)  Inverting both sides:

$$x^{s-1} > \frac{\Gamma(x+s)}{\Gamma(x+1)} > (x+1)^{s-1}$$

(3)  From the properties of the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function):

$$\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(x)}=x$$

(4)  Multiplying step(2) and step(3):

$$x^s > \frac{\Gamma(x+s)}{\Gamma(x+1)}\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(x)} = \frac{\Gamma(x+s)}{\Gamma(x)} > (x)(x+1)^{s-1}$$

Is my reasoning correct?  Did I make any mistakes or make any bad assumptions about the Gamma function?

Comment: It looks correct.

Comment: Thanks very much.  This form is much more intuitive to me.

Comment: Yes, it is correct and you do not have to suppose $x$ to be an integer.

Comment: Wow.  It is still true if $x$ is not an integer.  That is surprising.   Thanks for that detail.  :-)  I will have to read up more to understand why step(3) holds for a non-itnteger.